# When to use and what is the difference of a timer and thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Just now have some confusion about timer and thread, see below example, Both codes provide the same result (Do some checking every 60 seconds), so when should I use a timer and when should I use a thread to handle jobs when they're providing the same result?

Use Thread:

```
Thread checkJob = new Thread(checkStatus);
checkJob.Start();

protected void checkStatus()
{
   //Do Checking here
   Thread.Sleep(60000);
}
```

Use Timer:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timer time = new Timer();
            time.Interval = 60000;
            time.Tick += time_Tick;
            time.Enabled = true;
        }

      void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Do Checking here
            }
```

Comment: It completely depends on what you are doing. Both options are good choices in different situations.

Comment: In which situation thread is better? thread use extra resources when compare to a timer.

Comment: I added a short answer to explain that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the task that is performed periodically is very short, and will not get in the way of processing on the thread that the timer runs, then a timer is a reasonable choice.

On the other hand, if the periodic task takes a significant amount of time, and you cannot afford to have the main thread interrupted to perform it, then a separate dedicated thread is a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the timer you're using. If you're using a WinForms timer then your callback will fire on the gui thread. If you've got a lot of work to do then this will cause your application to block until you've finished, which will make for a bad user experience.

If you're using one of the other timers then they'll fire on a thread in the thread pool. Even here you'll want to avoid doing anything to long, but it won't block your gui thread. However, you're need to ensure you marshal any calls into the gui using the `BeginInvoke` method.

Starting your own thread is good if you're got long running tasks to do every time the timer fires, but once again you'll want to marshal calls back to the gui thread. Rather than using `Thread.Sleep` it's better to use an `Event` so that you can detect when the rest of the system is shutting down:

```
ManualResetEvent stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Thread checkJob = new Thread(checkStatus);
checkJob.Start();

protected void checkStatus()
{
   //Do Checking here
   while(stopEvent.Wait(60000) == false)
   {
     // Do processing
   }
}
```

Now you can stop the thread by calling `stopEvent.Set()`

Answer (score 2):

You can view a thread as a "sub-process"; a process can have multiple threads, allowing it to perform several operations in parallel. A thread is an expensive system resource; it uses a CPU when it's active, and allocates its own call stack (1MB by default). Using a thread to perform periodic actions is a waste of precious resources, and doesn't scale well.

A timer, in the other hand, is much cheaper. It's just a time-controlled trigger that does nothing most of the time, except when it's time to execute your code. It's the right choice in your case.

Comment: @User2012384, this question doesn't really make sense... they're too different to make this kind of comparison. They just don't have the same purpose; it's as if you were asking which is better between a saw and a hammer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use Timer - it is more suitable when it comes to resource consumption. 
Setting up a new thread is quite expansive. 
By the way in case you would like to use Thread you should set it to IsBackground=true, so that it can finish its execution when the application is shutdown.

Comment: Setting up a new thread that is expected to run forever and sleep for 60 seconds at a time, is not expensive